# ms access query not displaying what I want lol

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple song site ms access database I have an album table with some attributes one of them is album name and a song table with one of the attributes Title which is the songs title I'm trying to run a select query for displaying all the songs and their tables but whenever I run it it displays the songs a couple of times each time it's related to different album so basically the song is in all the albums (that's not how it's supposed to be[The table with all the albums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX29y.png))
[The queries output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXy0c.png)
[The queries syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALlUh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have created a *Cartesian* (multiplying) join between the tables.

What you miss, is to specify a *join* between the tables on AlbumID.

Look up a primer on SQL and joins.